# Connect to SQL Server on another computer with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm having issues connect with PHP to my SQL Server running on my other computer.

I can connect to the database using DataGrip **but only when not entering the database name** and I can't login to the database using PHP.

I´m using this to connect:

```
$serverName = "tcp:192.168.1.114, 1433";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "Database",
    "Uid" => "user",
    "PWD" => "password",
);
//Establishes the connection
$dbh = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($dbh === false) {
    echo "Connection error Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($dbh, $sql);
if ($getResults === false) {
    //echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
```

I´m getting this error:

```
Connection error Error (sqlsrv_connect): Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42000
            [SQLSTATE] => 42000
            [1] => 4060
            [code] => 4060
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'User'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'gottis'.
        )

)
```

I have enabled TCP connections and opened the firewall. I have also granted access to the user I'm trying connect with.

DataGrip only works if I don't specify the database, if I do write database name when connect with DataGrip it also gives me the same error as my PHP script.

I have tried all solutions I can find, the issue is probably something easy?

EDIT:

I get this error:

```
2021-05-10 23:27:48.69 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2021-05-10 23:27:48.69 Logon       Login failed for user 'user'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Database'. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.114]
2021-05-10 23:27:54.65 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'user'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.114]
2021-05-10 23:27:54.65 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
```

Comment: Does the `LOGIN` have a `USER` mapped in the declared database? What permissions does the `USER` have? What is the actual authentication error that is logged on the SQL Server (not the one presented back to the application)?

Comment: Hi @Larnu . How do you mean? I set the error code in the original post.

Comment: That's the application error, not the error in the (SQL Server) logs. What about the `USER` mapped to the `LOGIN` I asked about? What about the permissions of said `USER`?

Comment: Do you mean in the Security -> Logins path? The user has all server roles. User mapping is mapped to that specific DB.

Comment: No, the `USER` *mapped* to the `LOGIN`. A `LOGIN` is an instance object, I'm asking about the database `USER` object. Seems like you haven't created it.

Comment: @Larnu thank you! I did create a login but i still get the same issue.

Comment: But have you created a `USER`..?

Comment: @SimonGottberg In SQL Server a `LOGIN` is an instance-level principal that could potentially have access to none, one or multiple databases. A `USER` is a database-level principal that is denied/granted access to objects within a specific database. You authenticate to an SQL Server instance using a `LOGIN` principal that then has a "default database" setting as well as mappings to specific `USER` principal/s at the database level.

Comment: That said, State 38 suggests that the requested database in your connection string may not even exist on your SQL Server instance. Ref: [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error).

Comment: The issue was that the user was not created, thanks for the help!